# running into error of "UNREACHABLE" "permission denied" while running ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, centos7, permission-denied, unreachable-code

I entered this code `ansible all -m ping` to verify that the host that I added is running under ansible server 
but I get that error message:

> 192.168.186.137 | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).\r\n", 
>       "unreachable": true
>   }

so how to make that ip address reachable?

Comment: Can you SSH directly to that host? Is there network connectivity between the ansible host and the target host on the port that SSH is listening on?

Comment: One thing to note would be that ansible will ssh using the host user or the user through which command is getting executed. ssh may be established for a different user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have an `inventory` with the correct settings to connect to your host.

E.g.

```
  [local_test]
  hostname_of_host ansible_ssh_user=<your_ssh_user> ansible_host=<ip> ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<path_to_key>
```

Call Ansible with `ansible local_test -i inventory`.

Also, make sure you can connect to your host. Place those variables in the inventory file.